# how to detect the guest windows interpreter: cmd or powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, go, cmd

I am developing a go CLI tool which triggers terminal commands in different OSs.

I do not have much idea about Windows 10, so I will ask you this basic question: how to detect on which kind of windows shell my binary is run? (cmd or powershell).

I am wondering if this is feasible by reading environment variables.

I can see a set of potential candidates, specially `PSSessionOption` and `PSSesionConfigurationName`.

[image]

On the cmd side, there is `SESSIONNAME` and `ComSpec`.

[image]

[image]

- Are these good environment variables to detect the windows shell type?
- Or they are often overwritten by other applications?
- Could you please suggest me any other alternative environment variables for this purpose?
- As a fallback, is there any other method to identify the host shell type in windows?

Comment: Why does it matter which shell your program was launched from? Your interaction with that shell is pretty limited. If you're triggering terminal commands, they won't be running in the shell that launched your program, you'd have to run them in a shell chosen explicitly when you call `exec` anyway.

Comment: @Adrian: thanks for the answer. In my use case, it really does. My exe triggers a chain of commands which result generate a set of `bat` and `ps1` files to execute. I am not sure if executing the `bat` is a good choice from powershell. For sure, `ps1` is not for cmd. Ideally, if I would be able to unambiguously detect PS/cmd I would be able to make a choice of which script to execute.

Comment: @Adrian: a precise workflow would be: 

1. `cli install pythonmodule` 
2. cli fetches the pythonmodule from github
3. cli invokes `python -m venv avirtualenv` to create a virtual environment for the above python module dependencies.
4. cli activates the virtual environment above. Here there is the option of executing `./avirtualenv/Scripts/activate.bat` and `./avirtualenv/Scripts/activate.ps1`.

I have very little experience developing for PS, so I am not 100% sure if I could safely execute the `bat` script in PS and not having unexpected results.

Comment: It still doesn't matter what shell launches your application. When you run an external script, you're not running it in the shell that spawned you process, you're running it in a new shell.

Comment: @Adrian: you were actually right - after deeper testing, PS was able to swallow the `bat` script without any further issues :-)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
package main
import "os"

func main() {
   if os.Getenv("PROMPT") != "" {
      println("Command Prompt")
   } else {
      println("PowerShell")
   }
}
```

or this:

```
if _, ok := os.LookupEnv("PROMPT"); ok {
```

Although, as others have said, it's probably not a good idea to do, whatever it is you're trying to do. Whatever `.bat` or `.ps1` script you're trying to work up, you could just do it with Go directly. Go programs can have pretty much the same access to your system as the other types.